# Achieve the opposite of __VA_OPT__ in variadic preprocessor function-like macros

Tags: c++, preprocessor, variadic

How can I achieve the opposite effect of **VA_OPT**(), expanding only, if there are no variadic arguments in **VA_ARGS**. Something like **VA_NOT_OPT**().

Example:

```
#define MY_MACRO(...) __VA_NOT_OPT__(default) __VA_ARGS__
```

`MY_MACRO()` expands to `default`

`MY_MACRO(arg)` expands to `arg`

What I really want is a single optional parameter with a default value. But I think the C-Preprocessor doesn't support this. But maybe someone knows better than me.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you'd like to achieve? Why not use a variadic function template instead?

Comment: the oppositive of variadic is fixed number of arguments, It is unclear what problem you face, or why you think you need the "opposite of _VA_OPTS__"

Comment: Are you sure you want a MACRO. In C++ you should first check of variadic templates cannot solve your problem. MACRO's have their uses but are not the first thing you should try

Comment: I can think of cases where a variant of `__VA_OPT__` that conditionally expands to either A or B depending on whether the number of variadic arguments is zero (i.e. a `__VA_OPT__` with a else branch) may be useful, although those can possibly be rewritten to use the standard `__VA_OPT__` as well. I cannot however think of a case where a variant of `__VA_OPT__` with only the else case, as stated in the question, can be useful.

Comment: @WeijunZhou You can build `__VA_OPT_CONDITIONAL__(A, B)` out of this (`__VA_OPT__(A) __VA_NOT_OPT__(B)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a little conditional expansion macro pretty easily, so that `VALUE_IFNOT(1, args)` expands to nothing and `VALUE_IF(0, args)` (or in this case `VALUE_IF(, args)` too) expands to `args`:

```cpp
#define VALUE_IFNOT_TEST(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define VALUE_IFNOT_TEST0(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define VALUE_IFNOT_TEST1(...)
#define VALUE_IFNOT(COND, ...) VALUE_IFNOT_TEST ## COND ( __VA_ARGS__ )
```

Then your "opposite of `__VA_OPT__`" macro looks like `VALUE_IF(__VA_OPT__(1), value)`. This will expand to `VALUE_IF(1, value)` and nothing if there were variadic arguments and `VALUE_IF(, value)` and `value` if there weren't.

For example https://godbolt.org/z/Kbc5jxEKf

```cpp
#define TEST(...) VALUE_IFNOT(__VA_OPT__(1), std::printf("Test expanded on line %d with args '%s'\n", __LINE__, #__VA_ARGS__); )

int main() {
    TEST()      // TEST expanded on line 12 with args ''
    TEST(1)     // (no output)
    TEST(1, 2)  // (no output)
}
```

Comment: doesn't your `VALUE_IF(__VA_OPT__(1), val)` work exactly like `__VA_OPT__(val)` ?

Comment: @AbdulmalekAlmkainzi Good catch, fixed by swapping the conditional. Thanks!